# Serialize a map using a specific order

Tags: json, serialization, go

I have a map that uses string for both key and value. I have an array of keys that specifies the order of the values of the map.

I want to serialize that map to a JSON, but keeping the order defined on the array.

There is a sample code here: http://play.golang.org/p/A52GTDY6Wx

I want to serialize it as:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "age": "20"
}
```

But if I serialize the map directly, the keys are ordered alphabetically:

```
{      
  "age": "20",
  "name": "John"
}
```

I can serialize it as an array of maps, thus keeping the order, however that generates a lot of undesired characters:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "age": "20"
  }
]
```

In my real code I need to serialize the results of a database query which is specified in a text file, and I need to maintain the column order. I **cannot** use structs because the columns are not known at compile time.

EDIT: I don't need to read the JSON later in the specified order. The generated JSON is meant to be read by people, so I just want it to be as humanly readable as possible.

I could use a custom format but JSON suits me perfectly for this.

Thanks!

Comment: By definition, maps are unordered and whatever client you'll use won't guarantee that it will keep the order you serialized in. If you want order use arrays, otherwise use dictionaries.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the comment. I edited the question to make it clear that I won't have a client, the JSON will be stored and read by a person, and that person needs the fields in order.

Comment: How about a [data structure that actually does what you need](https://github.com/google/btree) instead of a workaround?

Comment: @ricsmania I'd seriously ask myself why I'm letting humans read JSONs, and consider a different approach.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer json is a verbose easy to read format that can be used  for several things and it should've replaced XML a long time ago.

Comment: @OneOfOne JSON easy to read? Compared to XML? Maybe a little. It is definitely not that much easier to write. Well, I have higher standards than that. Unless it is some sort of debugging output, of course. If it is input, I'd try use YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that specific requirement you really don't need to use `json.Marshal` at all, you can simply implement your own function like [this](http://play.golang.org/p/96e3MeAIAS):

```
type OrderedMap map[string]string

func (om OrderedMap) ToJson(order ...string) string {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.Write([]byte{'{', '\n'})
    l := len(order)
    for i, k := range order {
        fmt.Fprintf(buf, "\t\"%s\": \"%v\"", k, om[k])
        if i < l-1 {
            buf.WriteByte(',')
        }
        buf.WriteByte('\n')
    }
    buf.Write([]byte{'}', '\n'})
    return buf.String()
}
func main() {
    om := OrderedMap{
        "age":  "20",
        "name": "John",
    }
    fmt.Println(om.ToJson("name", "age"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and helping with the code. Although it's not a perfect solution, since it involves writing my own encoder, it did solve my problem.

Comment: Sadly Go went out of it's way to ensure that maps are unordered, so really there's no other way around it using a map, a btree could work but it will get messy in the wrong run.

Comment: Using range over map[string]string is defined as random. Though this example produces the right order on some architectures, it isn't guaranteed to.

Comment: @ericchiang not anymore actually, they ensured that in 1.4.

Comment: @ericchiang I know, I was replying to "Though this example produces the right order on some architectures", they changed that to make sure it's always random

Answer (score 15):

You need to implement the `json.Marshaler` interface on a custom type. This has the advantage of playing well within other struct types.

Sorry, you're always going to have to write a little bit of JSON encoding code.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type KeyVal struct {
    Key string
    Val interface{}
}

// Define an ordered map
type OrderedMap []KeyVal

// Implement the json.Marshaler interface
func (omap OrderedMap) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    buf.WriteString("{")
    for i, kv := range omap {
        if i != 0 {
            buf.WriteString(",")
        }
        // marshal key
        key, err := json.Marshal(kv.Key)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        buf.Write(key)
        buf.WriteString(":")
        // marshal value
        val, err := json.Marshal(kv.Val)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        buf.Write(val)
    }

    buf.WriteString("}")
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}

func main() {
    dict := map[string]interface{}{
        "orderedMap": OrderedMap{
            {"name", "John"},
            {"age", 20},
        },
    }
    dump, err := json.Marshal(dict)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", dump)
}
```

Outputs

```
{"orderedMap":{"name":"John","age":20}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest solution: https://github.com/iancoleman/orderedmap

Although it might be slow as it's mentioned [here](https://github.com/iancoleman/orderedmap/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MapSlice implementation similar to what YAML v2 offers. It can do both Marshal and Unmarshal.

https://github.com/mickep76/mapslice-json

Comment: The problem with that library is that it is not concurrency safe and follows a singleton pattern: https://github.com/ake-persson/mapslice-json/blob/22c8edf578070fd6f77d14f95a6acd45fd89ccb4/mapslice.go#L23