# Prevent alphabetically ordering json at Marshal

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I want to prevent alphabetically reordering at Marshal. My script is below. `{"key3": "value3", "key2": "value2", "key1": "value1"}` is reordered to `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}` by Marshal. I thought [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182923/serialize-a-map-using-a-specific-order) may be close issue. But I could not solve my issue. Is there way to solve this?

#### Script

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    obj := `{"key3": "value3", "key2": "value2", "key1": "value1"}`
    var o map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(obj), &o)
    fmt.Println(o)
    r, _ := json.Marshal(o)
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

[play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/H19JwUwOvr8)

- `fmt.Println(o)` is `map[key3:value3 key2:value2 key1:value1]`.
- `fmt.Println(string(r))` is `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}`.

Thank you so much for your time. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you’re trying to solve? Maps aren’t ordered so the order of serialization shouldn’t matter. If it does matter for some reason, you have to write it out yourself like in the linked answer.

Comment: In golang, a map is unordered. If you want to preserve the order, you might need to parse the string to a struct (with fixed fields) or to a custom type with your own parsing methods. If you choose the latter, you will need a slice to store the order.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your advice. I thought I may be misunderstanding from your advice. I want to update the json object and output it. But when I use Marshal, the json object is reordering. For example, I want to update ``{"key3": "value3", "key2": "value2", "key1": "value1"}`` to ``{"key3": "value3", "key2": "updated value2", "key1": "value1"}``. I use ``map[string]interface{}`` because keys of json sometimes changes.

Comment: @leaf bebop Thank you for your advice. I had thought I cannot use a struct because the keys of json sometimes changes. So I used ``map[string]interface{}``.

Comment: In that case you will need implent your own parsing method.

Comment: @Elsa but what about the linked answer doesn’t allow you to order the output. Note that not only are maps unordered in Go, but json objects are as well, so whatever is decoding them may not preserve the order either.

Comment: @leaf bebop Thank you for your advice. I will think the solution from your advices.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for your advice. I will think the solution from your advices.

Comment: In JSON, [**"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"**](http://json.org) so order doesn't make any sense on the JSON side of things either.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can preserve the order like this:

```
type OrderedMap struct {
    Order []string
    Map map[string]string
}

func (om *OrderedMap) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    json.Unmarshal(b,&om.Map)

    index:=make(map[string]int)
    for key:=range om.Map {
        om.Order=append(om.Order,key)
        esc,_:=json.Marshal(key) //Escape the key
        index[key]=bytes.Index(b,esc)
    }

    sort.Slice(om.Order, func(i,j int) bool { return index[om.Order[i]]<index[om.Order[j]] })
    return nil
}

func (om OrderedMap) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var b []byte
    buf:=bytes.NewBuffer(b)
    buf.WriteRune('{')
    l:=len(om.Order)
    for i,key:=range om.Order {
        km,err:=json.Marshal(key)
        if err!=nil { return nil,err }
        buf.Write(km)
        buf.WriteRune(':')
        vm,err:=json.Marshal(om.Map[key])
        if err!=nil { return nil,err }
        buf.Write(vm)
        if i!=l-1 { buf.WriteRune(',') }
        fmt.Println(buf.String())
    }
    buf.WriteRune('}')
    fmt.Println(buf.String())
    return buf.Bytes(),nil
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TxenZEuy_u0

Please note that json spec says objects are unordered, which means other client may not respect the order you preserve.

Comment: @Ieaf bebop:  Spent whole day to figure out the solution to a similar problem. This idea helped to solve it finally. Thanks a lot

Comment: A note to people in the future: if your JSON isn't extremely simple this won't return it in order. The sort is based on first appearance of the key in the bytes so if your first key has a value that includes the strings of other keys they will appear before the actual second key.